# how can i setup comodo SSL in kong api gateway using helm?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-helm, kong, kong-ingress

i wanna ask something, how can i setup comodo SSL in kong api gateway using helm? cause i've been installed using repo helm chart on documentation, and generate certmanager/lets encrypt. i want to try custom ssl in kong api gateways runnning from my k8s/kubernetes. thanks!